# Disabling developer mode or debugging feature in openerp?

Tags: debugging, odoo

How can I disable the debugging mode or developer mode for users other than admin? I tried to remove the button 'Activate developer mode', but the problem was, if I add '?debug' after the server address in the address bar, then again the user gets the developer mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following code will disable debug mode (Drop-down box) if user is admin (admin ID must be 1. If not then change session.uid === admin_id):

Create one xml file inside **your_module/static/src/xml** folder and add following code:

```
<templates>
    <t t-extend="ViewManagerAction">
        <t t-jquery="select.oe_debug_view" t-operation="replace">
            <select t-if="widget.session.uid === 1 and widget.session.debug" class="oe_debug_view"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</templates>
```

Now go to `__openerp__.py` and add your xml like this:

```
'qweb' : [
    "static/src/xml/your.xml",
],
```

Restart server, update your module and refresh the page.

You can refer this blog: [OpenERP Web Changes.](http://change-openerp-web.blogspot.in/)

Comment: thank you. however, does it also prevent any non-admin user enter the debug mode by adding "debug=1" in the url?

Comment: @farisfath25 Yes, it prevents the user to enter the debug mode even if he/she enters "debug=1" in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You tried with logout.
default is its remove when we log off.

Comment: no. its  not like that.only the admin should have the access to debugging mode. no other user should get it even if they try to add '?debug' in the address bar

Comment: ok AnomA.I haven't much idea because i'm debug in eclipse :-)